# How to prevent .NET web application assembly from being optimized?

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, build

Attempting to do some remote debugging on a .NET 4 Web Application, which is comprised of one main Web App DLL plus various referenced DLLs.

App is being built by Team Build 2010 in Debug configuration and build output is copied up to the IIS folder on the web server (for our Dev environment); I'd like it to be un-optimized so that it can be debugged from developer PCs.

However despite setting optimized=false in the .csproj file for all configurations, the Web App DLL always complains about being optimized when attaching to it to remote debug:

> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Interestingly none of the other DLLs built in the same solution have this issue, so I'm wondering whether there is something special about the Web App project itself that always forces the optimization?

If so, is there a way to get around it? Or are we stuck unticking the 'Just My Code' option any time remote debugging is needed (which isn't ideal as you can't see all variable values and such).

Comment: Are you **100% positive** that the assembly loaded is the one you built with optimisations disabled?  I've never heard of VS lying about whether an assembly is optimised and I've never heard if it optimising an assebly built with the optimised option unticked.  Check in the modules list and compare timestamps - it may be that an out of date cached assembly is being loaded instead

Comment: Maybe it would help to build on your local machine, and drop the assembly (+ pdbs) in place manually.

Comment: as far as i know the web app dll, is built by IIS when you first access a page within the app, so your dll is never used. (unless you are using pre-compiled publish). still i dont see why optimization should trouble you , since .NET a assembly contains all meta-data you need to get all values.

Comment: Menahem - Correct, although the DLL sits within the IIS webroot, the actual one linked in debugging is coming from the \Temporary ASP.NET Files\ one, so possibly Dynamic Compilation recompiles it?

Comment: Oh, and the reason for getting the optimization removed is that Remote Debugging on an optimized DLL doesn't give the ability to inspect variables and see the data flow through functions (unless I'm configured incorrectly!).
Will read up more about Dynamic Compilation to see if it is responsible, and maybe play around with pre-compilation instead...